# Can I animate rotateY() on an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image spin with a css transition. I have a `transition: 2s transform linear;` and `transform: rotateY(720deg);`.

You can see an attempt in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24ek3dgj).

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: 10s font-size;
  transition: 2000s transform linear;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body background>
  <div><img id="text" src="http://raritea.com/raritea/images/logo.ico"/></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var init = function(){
   document.getElementById('text').style.transform = 'rotateY(360000deg)';
}
```

Comment: It will rotate, but not animate

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/24ek3dgj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a total stab in the dark, but as is often the case with these issues, the likelihood is that you have no *initial* state for this `transition` to work.

Add something like this to your non-transitioned state:

```
.my-non-transitioned-state {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}
.my-transitioned-state {
  transform: rotateY(270deg);
}
```

And it should work.  `transition` is a mathematically computed tag, and needs two numeric values to work.  Thus, if you only give it one state, it can't transition.  Or, if you give it a non-numerical state (like `background-size: cover`, for example), it won't work.

Ensure that your `transition` has both an *initial* and a *destination* state, and this should work.

## Edit: [A working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24ek3dgj/2/)

So, there's one additional thing to consider when you're adding these styles via JavaScript.

**Order-of-operations for page rendering:**

The super-simplified order of operations for page rendering:

1. Scripts in `<head>` run
2. DOM loaded
3. Scripts appended at end of `<body>` run
4. CSS applied
5. Late-bound script operations

Adding `setTimeout` (even with a time for 0) pops your JS call from step 1 to step 5, which is why the fiddle works.